# Bootstrap Jquery Pagination from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I have searched google lot for creating a dynamic pagination from json data. I know  jquery dataTables is a nice tool and it works fine for this puporse. But I don't want to use `<table>` tag. I want to draw data using `<div>` tag. Jquery dataTables didn't work without `<table>` tag.
My JSON data is given below.

```
{"1":"Welcome","2":"to","3":"Hello","4":"World"}
```

I want to use bootstrap pagination class for pagination

```
<ul class="pagination">
  <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want create this pagination dynamically by using js/jquery from json data.